# What is the estimated weight of COVID-19 viruses present in the body of someone with the disease?

Tags: covid-19

Pictures of this coronavirus have been published, and several details about its morphology, including a size around 120 nm.

My questions are:

1. What is the weight of a single COVID-19 virus? Can we assume a density similar to water leading to a weight of 4/3*PI*120nm^3 / 1000 = 4.2 10<sup>-21</sup> g if I'm not mistaken?
2. Approximately how many viruses of this type are present in the body of someone infected (including asymptomatic carrier), and thus what is the average weight per person?

   [This page](http://theconversation.com/meet-the-trillions-of-viruses-that-make-up-your-virome-104105) states *It has been estimated that there are over 380 trillion viruses inhabiting us, a community collectively known as the human virome*

   However, it focuses on harmless viruses and healthy people. I haven't found numbers related to someone infected by a virus.
3. How does this compares to poisons<sup>1</sup>? [This article](https://www.sciencealert.com/handle-with-care-the-world-s-5-deadliest-poisons) about the deadliest one, botulinum toxin, states: *Extrapolating from its effect on mice, an intravenous dose of just 10⁻⁷g would be fatal to a 70kg person*.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I understand it can't easily compare with poisons as a poison doesn't duplicates itself inside a body and the immune system, hopefully, plays a role here.</sub>

Comment: What medical use do you consider this information to have? What have you found online with your question? Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject. What made you ask this question? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no medical, scientific, or academic value.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I have edited my question. Let me know if you still think it still deserves being closed. Thanks.

Comment: As @CareyGregory points out, and I agree (see the first point in my previous comment), I still do not see any medical, scientific or academic value within your question so therefore it is questionable that it is likely to have an answer. Can you demonstrate **specifically** that your question has a medical value with similar scientific studies on weight of a single virus and how much viral load is required for sufficient infection to create symptoms?

Comment: @ChrisRogers I understand that the weight of this particular  virus can be considered a futile piece of information but there is a study about the density of influenza viruses (https://www.jbc.org/content/159/1/29.full.pdf) from which we might deduce their individual weights, so that's not completely pointless. While I have removed that particular question from my list, I'm still interested in knowing the cumulative weight of all coronavirus spreading now, i.e. when the sum of infinitesimal quantities started to matter. Are we talking about, say, kilograms of viruses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single CoV-2-SARS virus weight is around one femtogram (10<sup>-15</sup>g).

An infected person contains between one billion and one hundred billion viruses, i.e. between one and one hundred micrograms.

Estimating the number of contaminated people at a given time to 50 million (including undetected cases), we reach a worldwide number of five hundred millions of billions viruses, with a cumulative weight being somewhere between 100 g and 1 kg.

Source: [The total number and mass of SARS-CoV-2 virions in an infected person](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.11.16.20232009v1.full.pdf) by
Ron Sender, Yinon M. Bar-On, Avi Flamholz, Shmuel Gleizer, Biana Bernsthein, Rob
Phillips, Ron Milo

---

Update: 2021-02-15:
A more recent computation didn't focus on the weight but on the volume:

- [All the coronavirus in the world could fit inside a Coke can, with plenty of room to spare](https://theconversation.com/all-the-coronavirus-in-the-world-could-fit-inside-a-coke-can-with-plenty-of-room-to-spare-154226)

Comment: I'm curious what led you to ask this question. Now that you found this answer, do you foresee any scientific value to it?

Comment: Curiosity led me to ask this question, which by the way is the only one I ever asked on any SE sites, contrasting with 4000+ replies of my own. About its value, here is a quote from its source: *The global impact of SARS-Cov-2 is clearly evident from its influence on public health
and the global economy. Contrasting these global effects with the very moderate
cumulative mass of these viruses highlights the limits of our day-to-day intuition in
understanding and combating this pandemic and the need to rely on sound quantitative
information rather than gut feelings.*